# GoogleMaps V3 Only Displays 1 Polygon

Tags: javascript, maps, polygon

have a web page which displays weather charts from many sources.  You pick your source and outlines of the charts appear on a Google Map.  (See http://www.geoffschultz.org/weather_map.php Weather Charts/GMDSS/Forecasts - should draw 3 polygons)  Up until now all of the charts have been rectangular, but I just came across the need for non-rectangular charts.  I had coded the js with this in mind, but I have been baffled because only the last polygon drawn is displayed. Is there something that I'm missing with regards to multiple polygons?

The code is very simple.  It gets an array of bounding box coordinates.  For simple rectangles the array element looks like "-31,-32|2,25" and for polygons it just has more coordinates separated by "|".  If there are 2 coordinates, I draw a rectangle, otherwise I draw a polygon, closing it with the 1st point.

What am I doing wrong as it works great for rectangles?

-- Geoff

```
for (i in bb[selValue])
    {
    bb_lat_long = bb[selValue][i]["bb_lat_long"].split("|");
    if (bb_lat_long.length == 2) //Rectangle
        {
        lat_long = bb_lat_long[0].split(",");
        sw = new google.maps.LatLng(lat_long[0], lat_long[1]);
        lat_long = bb_lat_long[1].split(",");
        ne = new google.maps.LatLng(lat_long[0], lat_long[1]);
        bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne);
        bounding_box = new google.maps.Rectangle({map: map, bounds: bounds, fillOpacity: 0.05, strokeWeight: 1});
        }
    else // polygon
        {   
        poly_lat_long.length = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < bb_lat_long.length; j++)
            {
            lat_long = bb_lat_long[j].split(",");
            poly_lat_long.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat_long[0], lat_long[1]));
            }
        lat_long = bb_lat_long[0].split(","); 
        poly_lat_long.push(new google.maps.LatLng(lat_long[0], lat_long[1])); // close polygon with 1st point
        bounding_box = new google.maps.Polygon({map: map, paths: poly_lat_long, fillOpacity: 0.05, strokeWeight: 1});
        }

    }
```

Comment: Probably need to say what `bb[]` and `sel_value` are. As an aside, splitting a string results in strings, and you should `parseFloat` before using the values in `LatLng()` and the like, because they should be numbers. Odd things can happen if you use strings where numbers are prescribed.

Comment: bb[] is an array of bounding boxes.  [selvalue] selects the type of bounding box.  bb[selValue][i]["bb_lat_long"] contains a string as described above like "-31,-32|2,25" and for polygons it just has more coordinates separated by "|". 

All of that works.  I can step through the code via firebug and see the correct values for the LatLng and the Polygon.  I see it creating multiple (in this case 3) polygons, but only the last one is displayed.  If I remove the last Polygon from the bb array, the new last one displays, etc.

Comment: Oh, I added parseFloat with no change.

Comment: Do you have an example of bb[] for a polygon?  Or a link to a map that exhibits the problem or a jsfiddle that does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that it has to do with re-using the path in the new polygons (you are ending up with multiple polygons, the just all are the same, perhaps if you declare poly_lat_long locally (with var), or make a createPolygon function that would get function closure on the path.

I have seen this behavior before when clearing the path array using `poly_lat_long.length = 0;`
rather than `creating a new array (poly_lat_long = [])`.

[Thread from the Google Maps API v3 group discussing similar problem](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/2e9f6d618c24a61e)

Comment: Ding...ding...ding...We have a winner!  I never knew that this could be a problem.  Thank you very much!  I would never have found this.